# Do taller/larger individuals have a greater risk of developing cancer because they have more cells that could go rogue?

Tags: cancer, contributing-factors, tall-height, large-size, risks

I recognize this sounds like an immature/ignorant question, and I hope it doesn't rub anyone the wrong way, but I came across this CNN article claiming just that, and I was wondering if there is any truth behind it or if this is just an oddity (against the grain) article? CNN isn't exactly "scholarly" or "medical" research.  http://www.cnn.com/2013/07/26/health/time-height-cancer/index.html

**Do taller/larger individuals have a greater risk of developing cancer because they have more cells that could go rogue?**